# Spring Data Projections

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a `User` entity with plenty of fields (i omit the code because it is very long and i do not think it's important in this case, let me know if you need it).

This is part of my repository:

```
interface UserRepository: JpaRepository<User, String>{
    fun findByNameContainingIgnoreCase(name: String, page: Pageable): Page<UserProfile>?
}
```

Now, I defined the following projection:

```
interface UserProfile{
    fun getUsername(): String
    fun getName(): String
    fun getFavoriteTags(): MutableSet<Tag>?
    fun getFavoriteDocuments(): MutableSet<Document>?
    fun getAverageScore(): Double
    fun getUserPicPath(): String
    fun getDocuments(): MutableSet<Document>?
}
```

The problem is that i do not want to return the list of user documents, but the number of his documents. I tried with:

```
@Value("#{target.documents?.count}")
fun getDocumentsCount(): Int?
```

but it doesn't recognize the count field.

I also tried with:

```
@JsonIgnore
    fun getDocuments(): MutableSet<Document>?
    fun getDocumentsCount(): Int? =  getDocuments()?.size
```

but it doesn't recognize the default method implementation.

I don't know what else to try. Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not going to be able to use `count` in a Spring annotation because it's not an actual Collections method; it's an **extension function**.

You need to combine your two existing solutions. Try it with the Value annotation, but using the right `MutableSet` function:

`@Value("#{target.documents?.size}")`

Comment: I do not remember if I was wrong to write the post or if I really tried with #target.documents?count. If it's the second I'm an idiot because I wanted to write size, not count. I will try but in the end I opted for a solution with the DTOs. Thank you very much anyway for the answer.

Comment: If you feel like this is the appropriate answer to the question, feel free to mark accepted :-)